# Heroku - Keep Keys Hidden Upon Inpect Element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, secret-key

I have deployed an application to Heroku and have used the heroku config:set command to set environmental variables such as keys for certain things (Google Maps API, for example).  When I view the page and inspect element, the key shows up in the url in the console.  Should this be the case?  I was under the impression that keys should be kept hidden to keep others from knowing what they are for security reasons.  Please advise.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Anything which is sent to the client is not secret. That includes any values used in javascript.

But don't worry - most API's like Google Maps use a public key. And applications where you use Oauth only allow a whitelist of callback domains.

In fact in the [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) your API key is used in constructing the URLs used to request resources so attempting to hide it would be a true fools errand.

Some API's do however provide client secrets for calling the API from the server side. These should be kept secret and placed in an ENV var on the server.